# Responsiveness with Tailwind css in React

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, responsiveness, tailwind-css

Hello everyone for a bootcamp project I have created a blog page and while trying to make it responsive, I messed up styling too. I am attaching the figma version, my code and what I get as a reflection. I need your help with styling and responsiveness please.
[figma version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgub4.png)

[what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irr5i.png)

[rest of what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AehbO.png)]

```
import React from 'react';
import meditation from './images/meditation.png';
import trauma from './images/trauma.png';
import anxiety from './images/anxiety.png';
import SubsInput from '../../shared/subsInput/SubsInput';

function Blog() {
  return (
    <div className=" mx-auto text-justify md:m-0 ">
      <img
        className="justify-center rounded mx-auto py-7 p-12"
        src={meditation}
        alt="meditation"
      />
      <div className="max-w-[800px] mt-[90px] w-full h-screen mx-auto  flex flex-col justify-center ">
        <h1 className="py-14 mt-6 text-bold text-3xl">
          MENTAL HEALTH AND TECHNOLOGY
        </h1>
        <p className="uppercase mb-4">
          Technology and mental well-being might seem like profoundly
          antagonistic terms. However, there are excellent digital tools to help
          you reach mindfulness and to practice meditation. You can even use
          smartphone apps, virtual reality solutions and digital devices as a
          form of relieving stressing and achieving digital detox – as, after a
          while, you will be able to practice all types of anti-anxiety skills
          on your own. So, let The Medical Futurist show you how you can enhance
          your mental and emotional health with the help of technology.
        </p>
        <h3 className="uppercase py-5 text-xl ">
          THE NEED FOR TAKING CARE OF OUR EMOTIONAL HEALTH
        </h3>
        <p className="uppercase">
          “Just as we observe physical hygiene to stay well, we need to
          cultivate a kind of emotional hygiene too,” wrote the Dalai Lama on
          his Twitter-feed. There are three crucial points around His Holiness’
          statement. First and foremost, the popularity of health-enhancing,
          physically active lifestyle is soaring worldwide. Nevertheless,
          there’s always room for improvement: the WHO says that globally, 23
          percent of adults and 81 percent of school-going adolescents are not
          active enough. According to the organization, adults aged 18-64 should
          do at least 150 minutes of moderately intense physical activity each
          week, which is not unaccomplishable. Moreover, the numerically and
          statistically driven 21st-century mind could take a great inspiration
          and power from the various fitness trackers and wearables.
        </p>
        <p className="uppercase py-6">
          Secondly, emotional hygiene seems to be thrown into the shade
          nowadays. Somehow, the culture of busyness prevents us from squeezing
          some time for mental health into our packed schedules. Information is
          pouring on us from millions of communication channels; we are
          connecting with hundreds of ‘friends’ on social media, we are obsessed
          with data due to the fear of missing out and time management slices up
          our days into meetings and to-do-lists.
        </p>
        <p className="uppercase">
          The pressure to perform and the stress to achieve is the air every
          busy-bee is breathing. However, turbulent lifestyle comes with a
          price. No wonder so many people have mental health issues. In the US,
          that means one in five adults – more than 40 million Americans! On the 
          old continent, 27 percent of the population has to cope with mental
          disorders, which means 83 million struggling Europeans. In Asia, the
          prevalence of depression is 20 percent in Thailand, 19.9 percent in
          Taiwan, 19.4 percent in Korea, 17.5 in Malaysia and 16.5 percent in
          China.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="max-w-[800px] mt-[-200px] w-full h-screen mx-auto  flex flex-col justify-center">
        <h3 className="uppercase text-xl font-weight:600 sm:m-0">
          Sign up for The Healing blog
        </h3>
        <h6 className="uppercase mb-4 py-2 font-weight:600">
          A weekly, ad-free Blog that helps you stay in the know.
        </h6>

        <SubsInput className="" />
      </div>

      <div className="flex justify-center mb-10">
        <div className="w-5/6 flex flex-col lg:flex-row justify-between gap-4">
          <div className="w-full lg:w-6/12 relative">
            <img
              className=" "
              title="HEAL FROM TRAUMA"
              src={trauma}
              alt="trauma"
            />
            <span className="absolute bottom-1/4 left-5 w-max ">
              <p className="text-white text-start text-2xl font-bold bg-slate-400 opacity-90">
                HEAL FROM
              </p>
              <p className="text-white text-start text-2xl font-bold bg-slate-400 opacity-90 mt-1">
                TRAUMA
              </p>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="w-full lg:w-6/12 relative">
            <img className="" src={anxiety} alt="anxiety" />
            <span className="absolute top-5 left-3 w-2/6">
              <p className="font-medium text-sm md:text-lg text-start">
                TELL ME ALL I NEED TO KNOW ABOUT ANXIETY
              </p>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Blog;
```

I need to meet the deadline I would be very happy if I get help with styling and responsiveness.

Comment: Tailwind's responsive design works from 'small' to 'big'. So every class you write, will apply itself to mobile size or bigger. If you want to overwrite this behaviour, you'd use `md:class-name` or `lg:class-name` as an example, just like you did in your code. However, keep in mind, that all other classes you apply to this element also still apply. 

So if you write `lg:h-5 flex flex-col` it is not the same as `lg:h-5 lg:flex lg:flex-col`. E.g.
`<img class="w-16 md:w-32 lg:w-48">`
Check [The tailwind responsive docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design) for mor information.

Comment: Thank you but I can't get the logic, for example, when I make screen smaller some elements overlap the elements above them

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.